# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS problems after automatic suspend, vast file of errors on screen no functions

Tags: suspend

Hi to all I am new here and a novice Ubuntu user having escaped the clutches of Microsoft at last! I am getting a fairly regular issue with my system if left for a few hours after going into automatic suspend. I either have no functions available via keyboard or mouse **or** otherwise get a screen full of process information which I am unable to copy. Any help or suggestions gratefully received!
N.B. I am really pleased with the setup other than this glitch, only way I can think of sharing the screen is to take picture and try to post it but it is not ideal as there are pages of info.
Many thanks in advance.
*Rather than spend hours playing with the system, I decided to disable suspend for the time being, I have lived without for quite a while now. I have read around the sites/forums that devote time to Linux based systems and have notices a few useful suggestions so will investigate in due course. Thanks for the advice, much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From documents](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspend.html.en)

> Some computers have problems with hardware support which mean that they may not be able to suspend properly. It is a good idea to test suspend on your computer to see if it does work before relying on it.

So you can disable suspend fro Settings > power:

[image: suspend off]

**EDITED**

Changed the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. Command:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

if lightdm is already installed. Command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

A screen appears in the terminal.
Follow the instructions, select lightdm.

[image: lightdm]
[image: lightdm]

**Reboot**

Comment: [@OldGitU.K.](https://askubuntu.com/users/937496/oldgitu-k) see edit.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I can't make a difference to your status as I am new on here, but not in life! Best.

Comment: [You can accept the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.